# Adding RTL and LTR support to VIM

Tags: vim, right-to-left, hebrew

I am a hebrew speaker (which is written right to left) 
so in my vimrc file I added the following

```
"-hebrew-----------------------------------------
func! ToggleHebrew()
  if &rl
    set norl
    set keymap=
  else
    set rl
    set keymap=hebrew
  end
endfunc
imap <f2> <c-o>:call ToggleHebrew()<cr>
map <f2> :call ToggleHebrew()<cr>
"-end-hebrew-------------------------------------
```

When I edit english only text it works, when I edit hebrew text it works.
When I edit text which contains both it doesn't work.

Here are two screenshots of the two modes
with English and Hebrew:

[image: english mode and hebrew mode]

So can someone show me the plug-in to fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to https://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15087

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an exact duplicate has been asked and answered on https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15087.